# How to eliminate loops for comparison operations in matlab?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, vector, vectorization

I am trying to eliminate the following loop in MATLAB, which finds the indices that a vector lies between. Since I'm performing this calculation with a loop, it takes an extremely long time to run (upwards of 20 minutes), and I need to run it very often.

MATLAB CODE:

```
% Clear window and variables
clc;
clear;

% Input Arrays
x = [0 0.5 0.51 0.49999 1]

xi= [0.25 0.47 .9 0.4]

% Create empty array
pos = double.empty;

% Find indices
for j = 1:length(xi)
    for k=1:length(x)-1        
        if ( (x(k) <= xi(j)) && (xi(j) < x(k+1)) )
            pos = cat(2,pos,k);
            break;
        end
    end
end

pos
```

This loop will return the indices or edges of x, that the values of xi lie between. I am using this loop for approximating a hardware implementation of linear interpolation, so I don't want to use any built in linear interpolation functions from MATLAB. 
I know that I can use the histc() function to find the edges, but I don't want to use any built in functions where I can't see the source code and implement that in hardware. I need something more straightforward.

I tried breaking up the code into a while loop and a for loop, but that code still didn't run quickly.

x is a vector that is size 4000x1 and is not necessarily in order due to errors from quantization. This doesn't matter for my purposes.

xi is a vector that is 100000x1 and is not in order

So as an example, if

x = [0 0.5 0.51 0.49999 1]

xi= [0.25 0.47 .9 0.4]

then we should get in return (using matlab indexing starting at 1):

pos = [1 1 4 1]

Comment: So you don't want to use logical indexing or `find` as well?

Comment: @m.s., Basically, I plan to implement the loops in hardware. I just want some implementation that will perform the same operation as the loops, but faster. find() might work. I can't use histc() because the edges have to be monotonically increasing and my data set doesn't have that characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1: Fully vectorized**

If you are allowed to use [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), this could be one approach with it -

```
xt = x.'; %//' save transpose of x to be used at two places later on
[~,pos] = max(bsxfun(@le,xt(1:end-1),xi) & bsxfun(@gt,xt(2:end),xi),[],1)
```

---

**Approach #2: Partially vectorized**

You can get rid of the innermost loop to have a partially vectorized solution like this -

```
pos = zeros(length(xi),1);
for j = 1:length(xi)
    pos(j) = find((x(1:end-1) <= xi(j)) & (xi(j) < x(2:end)),1);
end
```

Comment: I ended up using the first approach with bsxfun